# Combine keyboard macros with hotkey?

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a macro for a fighting game and I think I'm going about this the wrong way. Can I store these series of actions as their own objects? I have it set up to perform the series of keys to perform a skill but what if I want to combine the skills with a single hotkey? Like:

```
 keyboard.is_pressed('1'): 
 Skill1(), Skill2()
```

This is my code;

```
def Skills():
    while True:
            #Skill 1
            if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
                keyboard.press_and_release("q")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                keyboard.press_and_release("q")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                keyboard.press_and_release("q")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                keyboard.press_and_release("r")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                keyboard.press_and_release("d")
            #Skill 2
            if keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
                keyboard.press_and_release("e")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                keyboard.press_and_release("e")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                keyboard.press_and_release("e")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                keyboard.press_and_release("r")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                keyboard.press_and_release("d")
Skills()
```

Comment: Try splitting the actions to a separate function and call them?

Comment: Okay yeah I think I got this to work.